# Calculate the value of every key in a dictionary recursively

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary like below, where every key has a total size that is equal to its first value plus the sizes of its additional keys.

I would like to know the size of every key:

```
dictionary = {'/': [23352670, ['a', 'd']], 'a': [94269, ['e']], 'e': [584, []], 'd': [24933642, []]}
```

The solution should look like:

```
{'/': [48381165], 'a': [94853], 'e': [584], 'd': [24933642]}
```

I am practicing recursion and I would really like to solve this with recursion.  I tried to write a recursive function, and made some progress, but was not able to do it for the full dictionary.

The function I wrote looks like:

```
def recursion(dictionary, key):

    #base case list is empty
    if not dictionary[key][1]:

        return dictionary[key][0]
    
    else:
        
        size = dictionary[key][0]
        for child in dictionary[key][1]:

            size += recursion(dictionary, child)

    return dictionary
```

I know it is completely wrong, but it is the best I could come up with. How do I solve this problem correctly?

Comment: why does your second return return dictionary, which has not been modified in your code as far as I can see?

Comment: How do you get `'a': [94853]` from the input ?

Comment: It's not "completely wrong", the only mistake you make is that your return the dictionary instead of the size. Your function should calculate the total for **one** item. The iterate over your original dictionary and call this function for each key, inserting key and result in a second dictionary.

Comment: Oh, and the `if`-branch is completely unnecessary. Just keep the `else`-branch.

Comment: @ScottC 'a' = [94269, ['e']] and 'e' has the value 584 (with no children/additional keys) so 'a' + 'e' = 94269 + 584 = 94853.

Comment: ```
def recursion(dictionary, key):

    #base case list is empty
    if not dictionary[key][1]:

        return dictionary[key][0]
    
    else:
        
        size = dictionary[key][0]
        for child in dictionary[key][1]:

            size += recursion(dictionary, child)

    return size

for key in dictionary:

    size = recursion(dictionary, key)
    dictionary[key][0] = size
```

like this I think

Comment: @kasper you can [edit] your question. Code in the comments is usually not the best way to communicate code information (because of the formatting restrictions).

Answer (score 2):

Your recursion is very close, you just need to return the sum:

```
def get_dictionary_sum(d):
    
    def get_key_sum(k):
        # Base case
        if d[k][1] is []:
            return d[k][0]
    
        s = d[k][0]
        for k2 in d[k][1]:
            s += get_key_sum(k2)
    
        return s
    
    return {k: get_key_sum(k) for k in dictionary}
```

You can then use dictionary comprehension to calculate the sum for each key:

```
print(get_dictionary_sum(dictionary))

Outputs:
{'/': 48381165, 'a': 94853, 'e': 584, 'd': 24933642}
```

An improvement on this is to use a LRU (least-recently-used) cache on the function, so if two keys use the same key in their sums, we only need to calculate the sum for that key once:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def get_dictionary_sum(d):

    @lru_cache(None)
    def get_key_sum(k):
        # Base case
        if d[k][1] is []:
            return d[k][0]

        s = d[k][0]
        for k2 in d[k][1]:
            s += get_key_sum(k2)

        return s

    return {k: get_key_sum(k) for k in dictionary}
```

For example, with the input:

```
dictionary = {
    'a': [23352670, ['b', 'b', 'b']],
    'b': [94269, ['c']],
    'c': [13213, []]
}
```

The lru cache will reuse the summation for 'b':

(With a print statement at the start of the `get_key_sum` function)

```
Summing a
Summing b  # Notice how we only need to calculate the sum of B once
Summing c
{'a': 23675116, 'b': 107482, 'c': 13213}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
dictionary = {
    "/": [23352670, ["a", "d"]],
    "a": [94269, ["e"]],
    "e": [584, []],
    "d": [24933642, []],
}


def compute_sizes(dct):
    def _get_size(val):
        out = 0
        for v in val:
            if isinstance(v, int):
                out += v
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                out += _get_size(v)
            elif isinstance(v, str):
                out += _get_size(dct[v])
        return out

    for k, v in dct.items():
        yield k, [_get_size(v)]


print(dict(compute_sizes(dictionary)))
```

Prints:

```
{'/': [48381165], 'a': [94853], 'e': [584], 'd': [24933642]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not "completely wrong", the only mistake you make is that your return the dictionary instead of the size. Your function should calculate the total for one item.

```
def recursion(dictionary, key):
    # if branch isn't necessary
    size = dictionary[key][0]
    for child in dictionary[key][1]:
         size += recursion(dictionary, child)
    return size # not dictionary

# Test
dictionary = {'/': [23352670, ['a', 'd']], 'a': [94269, ['e']], 'e': [584, []], 'd': [24933642, []]}
print(recursion(dictionary, '/'))
```

To create a new dictionary, just iterate over your original dictionary and create the new one, using the recursion function:

```
newdict = {k: recursion(dictionary, k) for k in dictionary}
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW here is a non-recursive solution (with apologies: I see now that you want to practice recursion!)

```py
def resolve(d):
    done = {}
    while True:
        new = {
            k: v + sum([done[ki] for ki in tail])
            for k, (v, tail) in d.items()
            if all([ki in done for ki in tail])}
        if not new:
            break
        d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in new}
        done |= new
    
    return {k: [v] for k, v in done.items()}
```

Example:

```py
d = {'/': [23352670, ['a', 'd']], 'a': [94269, ['e']],
     'e': [584, []], 'd': [24933642, []]}

>>> resolve(d)
{'e': [584], 'd': [24933642], 'a': [94853], '/': [48381165]}
```